# Error : React says .map() is not a function. API returns object and I cannot iterate over it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am a beginner when it comes to REACT.JS, I am currently trying to extract data from an API for a project, I am using "Axios" to send the get request, so when I use {data} and get the response , the response comes as an array and I can iterate through it, but the in another API when I do that it returns me an object and I am not able to iterate over it. Does anyone have any workarounds for this ?

[This is the response from the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzsyp.png)

I want to iterate over these objects, when the user selects one of the option, I want the app to pull the data from the respective child and feed the data to the chart.

Comment: Share your code with us

Comment: `.map` can only be used on arrays, not objects.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: share the response, related codes

Comment: I am getting data from the API, and trying to feed it as data to datasets(react-chartjs) to visualise the data as graphs.

Comment: I am sorry, I just updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through objects, too.

```
Object.keys(data).map(key => 
    <option value={key}>{data[key]}</option>
)
```

Comment: Thank you sir ! You are kind ;)